# Translating pseudocode into Python

Tags: python, pseudocode

This is the pseudocode I was given:

1. COMMENT: define a function `sort1`
2. INPUT: a list of numbers my list
3. print the initial list
4. loop over all positions i in the list; starting with the second element (index 1)

   COMMENT: at this point the elements from 0 to i-1 in this list are sorted
   loop backward over those positions j in the list lying to the left of i; starting at position i-1 continue this loop as long as the value at j+1 is less than the value at j
5. swap the values at positions j and j+1
6. print the current list

And this is the python code I came up with:

```
#define a function sort1
my_list=range(1,40)
print
print my_list
num_comparisons=0
num_swaps=0
for pos in range (0,len(my_list)-1):
    for i in range(pos+1,len(my_list)): # starting at position i-1 continue this loop as long
                                        # as the value at j+1 is less than the value at j
        num_comparisons+=1
        if my_list[i]<my_list[pos]:
           num_swaps+=1
           [my_list[i],my_list[pos]]=[my_list[pos],my_list[i]]

print my_list
print
print num_comparisons, num_swaps
```

I'm not sure I did it correctly though.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please review [ask]... have you tried running it? what is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: this looks like homework. not sure if this is the right place to ask for help

Comment: A good way to verify it is correct is to decide what the intent was, and then check with some input data that it gives you the results you expect. Just "translating" it without knowing the goal or having an idea of the inputs/outputs won't help you much.

Comment: I was able to run the code without getting an error.. but think I am missing something because I did not put anything about position j in the code and can't figure out where it would go. I'm sorry I am extremely new to this...

Comment: I think what the psuedocode calls `i` is the variable `pos` in your code, so the variable I in your code `i` would correspond to what it called `j` in the second `COMMENT`. It would help to know what the result is supposed to be (what's supposedly being accomplished).

Comment: @martineau That makes sense! Thank you! It is supposed  to define a function that sorts a list with out recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in a comment, I think you effectively *do* have the `j` (as well as the `i`) the pseudocode COMMENT talks about. However, in your code, `i` is the variable `pos`, which would make the `j` what is named `i` in your code.

To see if your code works, you need to initially have an unsorted list—not the `my_list=range(1,40)` in your code (which is `[1, 2, 3, ... 38, 39]` and already in numerical order).

One thing you didn't do is define a `sort1()` function.

What is below is **essentially your code**, but I renamed the two variables to match the pseudocode COMMENT, and put (most of it) in a function definition where it's supposed to be.

Beyond that, I had to declare the variables `num_comparisons` and `num_swaps` (which aren't mentioned in the psuedocode) as `global` so they could be accessed outside of the function—otherwise they would have been local variables by default and only accessible *within* the function.

```
def sort1(items):
    """ Sort given list of items in-place. """
    # allow access to these variables outside of function
    global num_comparisons
    global num_swaps

    # initialize global variables
    num_comparisons = 0
    num_swaps = 0

    # starting at position i-1 continue this loop as long
    # as the value at j+1 is less than the value at j
    for i in range(0, len(items)-1):
        for j in range(i+1, len(items)):
            num_comparisons += 1
            if items[j] < items[i]:
               num_swaps += 1
               [items[j], items[i]] = [items[i], items[j]]

my_list = [6, 3, 7, 2, 9, 4, 5]

print 'my_list before sort:'
print my_list
sort1(my_list)
print 'my_list after sort:'
print my_list
print
print 'num_comparisons:', num_comparisons, ', num_swaps:', num_swaps
```

Output:

```
my_list before sort:
[6, 3, 7, 2, 9, 4, 5]
my_list after sort:
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]

num_comparisons: 21 , num_swaps: 10
```

Comment: Thank you! Every time I tried to define the function I kept getting an error and now I see why, I put the print statement and the list right after the function.